# ImportError: No module named 'TkTreectrl'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am pretty new to python and am trying to use the `MultiListbox`. It says I need to import `TkTreectrl`. I have already done `import TkTreectrl as treectrl` but it still give me the error.

After some reading online, I was under the impression I am supposed to add some file to the folder my program is in?

Can someone help me understand how exactly I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little checklist of what to do to get the file running:

```
1) Download the package file from the internet or get it whereever you can get it from
2) Unzip it (if nessecary)
3) Move it into the directory of your code file
4) Run your code, if there are no errors it will run.
```

I assume that the `MultiListbox` modules are in subfolders, you will need to call them like this:

`from MultiListbox.subfolder import *`

or

```
import Multilistbox
```

I hope I could help you!

Comment: i tried copying it to current folder then python folder in tcl, but none worked. could you please give me exact path